# Action never reaches reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I added a new reducer to my application. To test that it is working I am just trying to hook it up to one action. When this action is called though, I see it properly in my devTools execute as it should, but it never gets to the reducer. I am using redux persist v6 and think the issue is somewhere in there, my app has been extremely buggy since I have tried to persist more than one reducer.

my store:

```
const todoPersistConfig = {
  key: 'TodoReducer',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['todos'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const storageConfig = {
  key: 'StorageReducer',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['IDs'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['TodoReducer', 'StorageReducer'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
  ModalReducer,
  StorageReducer: persistReducer(storageConfig, StorageReducer),
  TodoReducer: persistReducer(todoPersistConfig, TodoReducer),
  AuthReducer
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, reducers);

export default function storeConfiguration() {
  const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    {},
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
    )
  );

  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { persistor, store };
}
```

my storage reducer:

```
import ADD_NOTIFICATION_ID from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  IDs: []
};

const storage = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NOTIFICATION_ID:
      console.log('called on');
      return {
        ...state,
        IDs:
        [
          ...state.IDs,
          {
            itemID: action.item.id,
            reminderType: action.reminderType,
            notificationID: action.notificationID
          }
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default storage;
```

the action that properly gets called:

```
export const addNotificationID = (item, reminderType, notificationID) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_NOTIFICATION_ID,
    notificationID,
    item,
    reminderType
  };
};
```

I had this action going to a different reducer before, but it was bugged so I am trying to make a new one and start fresh. But now, the console log I have in my reducer never even fires when the action does. It doesn't reach the reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer was my import. `{ ADD_NOTIFICATION_ID }` was what I should have done.

Answer (score 1):

It’s been a while since I last looked at redux-persist, but I suspect that this line might be an issue

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, reducers);
```

If you are persisting child reducers, then you don’t need to also persist the entire store.

Comment: I made the change and this did not fix the issue.

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: Take out persist on that reducer, if that fixes it, then look at how persist is starting up. You may not get data out of a persisted reducer till it creates the connect to where you persist the data.

Comment: I had an issue like this a year ago when I used this, but don’t remember the issue and without a working example it is difficult to remember. In my case I was late loading reducers and had to jump through hopes to get it to work

Comment: If my action that fires has to wait for something async do I need to do an async redux action? I took the persistance out of it and it didn't solve the problem, I think the issue then must be the action.

Comment: grabbing the notificationID for the action is asynchronous

Comment: I don’t see how that is async from the code you pasted.